# How to find characteristic polynomial of the following matrix:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> How to find characteristic polynomial of the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} B& C\\D&E\end{bmatrix}$$
where

$$B=\begin{bmatrix} n-1& 1&1&1&\ldots _{(\phi(n)+1) \text{times}}1&&&& \\1&n-1& 1&1&\ldots _{(\phi(n)+1)\text{times}}1&&&& \\1&1&n-1&1&\ldots _{(\phi(n)+1) \text{times}}1&&&& \\....\end{bmatrix}_{\phi(n)+1\times\phi(n)+1}$$

$$C=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1&\ldots\\1&1&1&\ldots \\....\\...\\\end{bmatrix}_{n-\phi(n)-1\times n-\phi(n)-1}=D^T$$

and $E$ is unknown.

Can I find the characteristic polynomial of $A$ in terms of $E$?

**For Example**:

Take $n=6$
then the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}B&C\\D&E\end{bmatrix}$$ where $$B=\begin{bmatrix} 5&1&1\\1&5&1\\1&1&5\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$C=D^T=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and $E$ is unknown.

*Note*: $\phi(n)$ denotes the number of integers prime to $n$ and less than $n$.
How to find the characteristic polynomial of $A$ in terms of the unknown matrix $E$.

Comment: There is a small mistake in your question, you wrote 'where $A = [...]$', but you surely meant 'where $B= [...]$'. It is clear that you have to use the fact that: $B = (n-2)I + J$, where $J$ is an all-ones matrix. What is $\phi(n)$ ?

Comment: @PseudoRandom;Question Edited

Comment: reread your dimensions my friend; it's non-sense.